# C++ File Operations

Tags: c++

As part of an assignment, I need to read data from a binary file which consists of `int`, `char` datatypes of data. This binary file is divided into records 96 bytes each. I am trying to reading these 96 bytes into a `char` buffer and then trying to split them according to info I have. But I am getting nothing when trying to get `int` values from the buffer. Can you help me in this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *p;
    char temp[10];
    int val;
    fstream ifs,ofs;
    ifs.open("write.bin",ios::binary);
    if(ifs.read(buffer,96)) 
    {
        cout << "READ" << endl;
    }      
    p = buffer; 
    memcpy(temp,buffer,4);
    cout << temp << endl;
    val = atoi(temp); 
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

I used `strncpy` also in place of `memcpy`.
The output is 0 for `val` and blank for `temp`.

Comment: We could possibly help if you show us the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: didn't you forget `ios::in` flag in `ifs.open(...)`? try `doing ifs.seekg(0);` before calling `ifs.read(...)`.

Comment: What is the structure of your records? It seems, you are trying to read strings, where the data may be in some binary representation.

Comment: Try getting it working without reading from a file first. So, have a hard coded string of 96 `char`s, and just try using `atoi`, then try using `memcpy`, then try reading from the buffer. You'll get there (c:

Comment: Also, if you were really using C++ there are better ways of using `fstream`. At the moment you're half in C-land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atoi` transforms strings (char arrays) into integers. So something like `"42"` would return the integer `42`. The way your question is written, it sounds like the integers are simply stored as binary in the textfile.

A simple cast of the buffer pointer to the desired type plus a dereference should do:

```
/* read 96 bytes into char array buffer */
uint32_t your_number = *(uint32_t*)buffer;
cout << your_number << endl;
```

If you want to use `memcpy`, there's no need to copy to a char array, you can copy directly to an integer address:

```
uint32_t your_number;
memcpy(&your_number, buffer, 4);
cout << your_number << endl;
```

---

With plain C (not C++) this would be:

```
uint32_t your_number;
FILE *f = fopen("write.bin", "r");
fread(&your_number, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f); /* uint32's size is 4 bytes */
fclose(f);
printf("%d\n", your_number);
```

I chose `uint32_t` as a data type, because it is guaranteed to have 32 bits/4 bytes – `int` might, on some platforms/compilers, be of different size.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C-style functions, `read` does not return number or bytes read, instead, it returns `istream&`. So to check the result, call `ifs.gcount()` after `ifs.read()`.

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't itself fix his problem.

Comment: Well, it may be, I've check the program https://gist.github.com/2293977 on my computer using gcc and got non-empty output. The problem may be in the data.